# Google App Engine PHP: Multiple file upload

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Is there a way to allow multiple file uploads in one request to Google App Engine? [This guide](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2015/03/09/direct-file-uploads-for-php-5-5/) makes me believe that you can but I copied that demo and it doesn't seem to work for me.

**app.yaml**

```
application:    splink-api
runtime:        php55
api_version:    1

default_expiration: "1h"

handlers:
    - url: /handle_upload
      script: handle_upload.php

    - url: /direct_upload
      script:direct_upload.php
```

**direct_upload.php**

```
<?php
// Direct uploads requires PHP 5.5 on App Engine.
if (strncmp("5.5", phpversion(), strlen("5.5")) != 0) {
    die("Direct uploads require the PHP 5.5 runtime. Your runtime: " . phpversion());
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="handle_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Send these files:<p/>
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple="multiple"/><p/>
        <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**handle_upload.php**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
print_r($_FILES);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => arryn.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => vfs://root/uploads/0
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 721332
                )

        )

)
```

Using a simple php server with the same code results in:

```
Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => arryn.jpg
                    [1] => baratheon.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /private/var/folders/rc/z5ky3d3s29v0bsdllnzvpj8r0000gn/T/phpUt5H8S
                    [1] => /private/var/folders/rc/z5ky3d3s29v0bsdllnzvpj8r0000gn/T/phpijjaNO
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 721332
                    [1] => 234717
                )

        )

)
```

Can't see any errors in the logs and I've tried with really small files so that shouldn't be an issue. Testing locally on a dev server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `php.ini` I needed to change

```
max_file_uploads: 1
```

to

```
max_file_uploads: 100
```

This isn't very well documented in any of the demos or documentation I looked at.